# Python: get the most maximum values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding

I have a dictionary

```
{u'__': 2, u'\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430': 1, u'\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443': 1, u'\u041d\u0430\u043c': 1, u'\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043d': 1, u'\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043c\u0438': 1, u'\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0437\u043d\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438': 1, u'\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e,': 1, u'\u0432\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0435\u043c\u0443': 1, u'\u043d\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0439': 2, u'\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0443': 1, u'\u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0430': 1, u'\u0434\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0435\u0439\u0448\u0435\u043c.': 1, u'[![\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441](//yastatic.net/lego/_/la6qi18z8lwgnzdsar1qy1gwcwo.gif)](//www.yandex.ru)': 1, u'\u0412\u0430\u043c': 1, u'\u0430': 102, u'\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441\u043e\u0432,': 1, u'\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044c': 1, u'\u0438': 90, u'\u0440\u0430\u0437.': 1, u'[cureit](http://www.freedrweb.com/?lng=ru)': 1, u'\u043d\u0435': 9, u'\u0438\u043b\u0438': 2, u'\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e': 1, u'\u043d\u0430': 11, u'\u043d\u043e': 17, u'\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u044b': 1, u'\u041c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u0448': 5, u'\u0445\u043e\u0442\u0438\u0442\u0435': 1, u'[\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043e\u0439': 1, u'\u0432\u044b': 5, u'\u0446\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0439': 1, u'\u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044b': 3, u'\u0415\u0441\u043b\u0438': 2, u'\u0422\u0430\u043a\u0436\u0435': 1, u'\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043b\u0438': 1, u'\u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e': 1, u'**\u0412': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b),': 1, u'\u041f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u0438](//help.yandex.ru/common/?id=1111120).': 1, u'\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0443': 1, u'\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0443\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0435': 2, u'\u0432': 69, u'\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043c': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0431\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435': 1, u'\u0443\u0442\u0438\u043b\u0438\u0442\u043e\u0439': 1, u'\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435': 4, u'\u0432\u043e\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441': 1, u'\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435.': 1, u'\u043f\u043e': 24, u'##': 1, u'\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f': 1, u'\u0443': 37, u'(\u043d\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440,': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u2192': 1, u'\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441': 4, u'\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435': 2, u'\u043f\u043e\u0445\u043e\u0436\u0438': 1, u'\u043a\u0430\u043f\u0447\u0435\u0439': 1, u'\xab\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c\xbb.': 1, u'#': 3, u'cookies**.': 1, u'\u0431\u0443\u0434\u0435\u0442': 1, u'\u0427\u0442\u043e\u0431\u044b': 2, u'\u0441\u0432\u044f\u0437\u0438](//feedback2.yandex.ru/captcha/).': 1, u'\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u043e\u043c\u0443': 1, u'\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0431\u043b\u0435\u043c\u044b': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u043c,': 1, u'\u0441\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0430![](//yastatic.net/lego/_/la6qi18z8lwgnzdsar1qy1gwcwo.gif)\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u043c\u043e\u0433\u0443\u0442': 1, u'\u0432\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0445': 1, u'\u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e': 1, u'\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0431\u0435': 1, u'ip-\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0430,': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430,': 2, u'\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0439': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u043c\u0438': 1, u'\u0435\u0433\u043e': 4, u'\u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0442\u0430\u043a': 1, u'\u0440\u0430\u0437': 3, u'\u0441\u0435\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0438\u0442': 1, u'cookies,': 1, u'ip-\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0430.': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0436\u0435\u043d': 1, u'\u043d\u0430\u0436\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0435': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0434\u043b\u044f': 2, u'\u043e\u0439...': 1, u'[\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0435': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044e,': 1, u'\u0438\u0445.': 1, u'\u044d\u0442\u0438\u0445': 1, u'\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u043e\u0431': 9, u'\u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a,': 1, u'\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0443': 1, u'\u0434\u043e\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e': 1, u'\u0412': 6, u'\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0441\u044c?': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0439,': 1, u'\u0432\u044b\u043d\u0443\u0436\u0434\u0435\u043d\u044b': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u0438\u0432\u0448\u0438\u0435': 1, u'\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0438\u043d\u043a\u0438': 1, u'\u043a': 30, u'\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0438\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0443\u044e\u0449\u0435\u0439': 1, u'\u041d\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u043e,': 1, u'ip.': 1, u'\u0434\u0440\u0443\u0433\u0438\u0445': 1, u'\u0434\u0435\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e': 1, u'\u043e\u0442\u043a\u043b\u044e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044b': 1, u'\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u043c': 1, u'\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0438\u0435': 1, u'\u0432\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435': 1, u'\u0434\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f,': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0433\u043e': 2, u'\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e': 1, u'![](//mc.yandex.ru/watch/10630330?ut=noindex)': 1, u'\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430,': 1, u'\u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043c': 2, u'\u0436\u0430\u043b\u044c,': 1, u'\u0432\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0430': 1, u'\u043e\u0442\u043a\u043b\u044e\u0447\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u043e\u0442': 9, u'\u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0447\u0435\u0433\u043e': 1, u'\u043d\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440,': 2, u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b,': 1, u'\u044d\u0442\u043e\u043c': 3, u'\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0435': 1, u'\u044d\u0442\u043e\u0439': 1, u'\u0435\u0449\u0451': 1, u'\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u044b': 1, u'\u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0435': 1, u'\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442': 1, u'\u0434\u043e\u043b\u0433\u043e.': 1, u'\u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e': 2, u'\u041f\u043e': 3, u'\u0434\u0435\u044f\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438': 1, u'\u043e\u0442\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0430\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043c': 2, u'\u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u0432\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u043e\u043c\u043d\u0438\u043c': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u0441': 4, u'![](https://www.yandex.ru/captchaimg?ahr0chm6ly9zlmnhchrjageuewfuzgv4lm5ldc9pbwfnzt9rzxk9zdm5y2x2ukryv3ryogdaclb0bkjvevbntxjlq2dnrey,_0/1476178373/d4dbeb7c6b14f42a9352a0c4a457922c_1d31938b6816fc51509079a461b5ae7a)': 1, u'\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0439': 2, u'\u0412\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e,': 2, u'\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u043a\u0438,': 1, u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b': 5, u'\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e\u0439': 1, u'\u0441': 77, u'\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0443,': 1, u'\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440': 2, u'\u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u0430\u044e\u0442': 1, u'\u0432\u0430\u043c': 5, u'\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u043e\u0439,': 1, u'\u0447\u0442\u043e': 1, u'\u0432\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443.': 2, u'\u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c,': 1, u'\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043c': 1, u'\u043f\u043e\u0434\u043e\u0431\u043d\u044b\u0435': 1, u'\u0432\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044c': 2, u'\xabdr.web\xbb.': 1, u'\u0432\u043a\u043b\u044e\u0447\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'[\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441.xml](//xml.yandex.ru).': 1, u'\u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438.': 1, u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0447\u0438\u043d\u0435': 1, u'\u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043a\u043e\u0438\u0442\u044c': 1, u'\u043c\u044b': 3, u'\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e': 1, u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0434\u043b\u0435\u0436\u0430\u0442': 1}
```

I need to convert it encoding and get dictionary with 10 the biggest values.
I try to use

`print max(dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(10))[0]`
But it returns me nothing.
But how convert this string I don't know. I didn't find the way to do it.

Comment: You were probably looking for `sorted` rather than `max`: `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t:t[1], reverse=True)[:10]`, this will return `[('а', 102), ('и', 90), ('с', 77), ('в', 69), ('у', 37), ('к', 30), ('по', 24), ('но', 17), ('на', 11), ('об', 9)]`. You should use RemcoGerlich's `Counter` solution, though, I think that is more elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`max()` can only ever return a single value. Use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(yourdictionary)

print(counter.most_common(10))
```

Comment: @Petr: dict(counter.most_common(10))